# Wire Protocol for PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql, protocols

I am making a project and for that i have to mention a protocol name for that.So I read about Wire Protocols used by Microsoft and Oracle, the thing is I need some names for wire protocol that i can use in postgres.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/protocol.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question.  I would suggest the best "name" for the PostgreSQL wire protocol would be *libpq*, which is, of course, really just the name of the library used.  I recall seeing other line protocols being called by their library APIs.